# Use R to impose bubble data on an image

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

I want to take an image, like this:

[image: apes]

And I want to superimpose data bubbles on it, so it would look like this:

[image: apebubbles]

I want to do this in R (because I know R)

Let's imagine the bubbles represent IQ (or whatever) and I have the relevant numbers in a spreadsheet next to the species. How do I get ggplot (let's say) to know where on the image to put the bubbles?

Thank you!

Comment: Cowplot package ([vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html)) lets you superimpose an image behind a plot, but I don't think there would be any way for ggplot to know where the image lines were, you'd just have to adjust the x and y position of bubbles using trial and error.

Comment: thanks! must be a better way though - ggmaps would let you do something like this with a map, in which case the location of the city (new york) would be identified by ggplot through its coordinates. So, I'm guessing there has to be some way of doing the same thing with *any* image ...  :)